# slf4j logging - difference between the two error logging methods (with and w/o Throwable)

Tags: java, exception, logging, slf4j, error-logging

I am using [slf4j 1.7.x](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) for logging in our Java project. The [Logger](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) interface has multiple methods to log at *ERROR* level such as these two:

```
void error​(String msg, Throwable t)
void error​(String format, Object... arguments)
```

My question is, if I would like to log an exception in my catch block which of these two is considered better and what information is logged in which one, if I have it as follows?

```
try {
    // Code to call sdk for ABC Service
} catch (AbcServiceException | CredentialException | IOException e) {
    logger.error("Error during getting information from Abc", e);
    //OR
    logger.error("Error during getting information from Abc {} {} ", e.getMessage(), e.getCause());

    return null; // Or return some default value
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an opinionated answer, but I prefer the throwable-consuming APIs, as it provides multi-level stack trace and appears to be the most used API in projects.

Also remember that slf4j 1.6 or later can detect if last param in `Object[]` is an exception, it's easy to have parameterized logging with exceptions too - see http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#paramException for an example.

In the end, just writing `LOG.error("blah blah {} {}", arg1, arg2, exception)` has worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks @Adam, I was not aware of this change post slf4j 1.6. When you say **I prefer the throwable-consuming APIs** does that mean this:  `logger.error("Error getting information for id={} from Abc service", id, e);` And will it take care of logging the error `message`, `cause` and the full stacktrace?

Comment: In my experience it does so (at least when log4j1.2 and log4j2 backends were used, but I wouldn't expect any different behaviour for other logging backends).